# Migrate Ubuntu Studio 12.0.4 To New Machine Also Using Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: migration

I have been attempting to find the proper avenue to migrate my Ubuntu Studio 12.0.4 (Low Latency) user account, settings, and programs. My MAC is running a virtual Machine with the prior Ubuntu version mentioned on Parallels Desktop 7. I have a Ubuntu configuration that I'm comfortable with and I would loath having to spend hours tweaking everything to my liking.

*I utilized my laptop as a test machine and I question how to avoid any migration of drivers. I also seriously doubt they would be compatible, although I could be mistaken about this. Does anyone know how to do this without causing an unstable system?  As you can see from the title of my account I'm a Ubuntu Novice that is migrating from MAC OSX Lion & Windows 7 and these are totally different systems. Therefore, I require more instruction and descriptiveness than most. I am not well acclimated with Ubuntu yet.  However, I'm a quick learner and I'll figure out how to implement what's imparted on me.  Thank you in advance for any advise you take the time out to give me.

Comment: Hello! If you could start asking your questions on askubuntu.com instead of meta.askubuntu.com, that'd be great! Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Issues in OP situation

1. **Ubuntu Studio Kernel**

   Ubuntu Studio 12.04 default to low-latency kernel. I am not sure how that will fair in a VM.

   On the other hand, if plain Ubuntu 12.04 will be used in the VM, it is not sure if those audio/video related package will give same(or satisfactory) performance compare to Ubuntu Studio. This may also affect driver/device performance if Ubuntu is interfacing with USB pass through devices.
2. **Moving User account**

   This is actually the easy part.

   1. On old machine, tar the home directory of `username`, as `root`

      ```
      cd /home
      tar cjf username.tar.bz username
      ```
   2. On new machine, as `root`, copy username.tar.bz into `/home`

      ```
      adduser username
      cd /home
      rm -rf username
      tar xf username.tar.bz
      chown -R username:username username
      ```
   3. Login as `username`, all old setting will be there.

   Same `username` should be used on the new machine. Some packages save absolute path or the username in settings. Using same user name avoid any headache.

   However, this only cover user level settings. System level settings (eg. `/etc/`) is not cover here.

Comment: Thank you the VM is actually running 12.0.4 Low Latency so far so good but I haven't really attempted any daws or audio apps yet so I can't say how it will work in this environment.

Comment: The hardware like synthesizer, mic. recorder, etc are the stuff you should test if they are performing good. I encounter a case that they give !@#$ sounds even in a native setting and is pain to tune them.

Comment: :) I will be sure to do this the last thing I need is instability. I eventually wish to rid myself of other systems as it is much more cost effective to run Ubuntu. Therefore, a test environment is imperative so that I may tweak the system to run optimally.